# How to change style of GridViewItem UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP App which uses a GridView of images which have a behavior associated on a user tap.

Main.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DemoItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:DemoImages">
        <Grid>
                <Image
                    Source="{x:Bind ImagePath}"/>
              <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction 
                            Command="{x:Bind DoSomeAction}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Behavior>
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
    

</Page.Resources>

      <GridView
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ObservableCollectionOfItems}" //List of images 
            SelectionMode="Single"
            IsItemClickEnabled="false"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DemoItemTemplate}"> //defining different images 
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel
                        Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItemPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedPointerOverBackground"  Value="Green"/> // tried different properties here 
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
```

With this code I get a rectangle which has an ascent color when I click on my item. How do I modify the template so as to not have this rectangle? I tried manipulating the ItemContainerStyle but having no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With this code I get a rectangle which has an ascent color when I click on my item.

You need set the [SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.selectionmode?view=winrt-19041) property to `None` to disable the item selection of a `GridView`:

```
<GridView SelectionMode="None" ... />
```

And you could also modify `GridViewItem` style to find `BorderRectangle` and set `StrokeThickness` as 0 that could make rectangle hidden when item selected.